# Images not shown when localising Storyboard in Xamarin IOS

Tags: ios, xamarin

I am working on a project where we need to provide localisation support - (Localisation is provided based on user choice not based on System Settings. ). I have provided localisation support in storyboard and base localisation is also provided.

I was able to get the strings in TextFiled localised using the below code

```
var languageBundle =NSBundle.FromPath (resourcePath);
var storyborad = UIStoryboard.FromName ("MainStoryBoard", languageBundle); 
storyborad.InstantiateViewController ("ViewController");
```

But the images are not shown at all irrespective of language.

I have placed all my images directly in the Resource folder.

Is there any way to show the images ? Is am missing any information that need to added in the bundle when initiating the story board.

I am new to iOS Development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to get exact solution to this problem but i was able to do a workaround. Placing images under the respective locale folder could resolve  this issue.
I am using Xamarin studio for development so when i added the required images as links, some times it shown a positive result.